# ECS Task AZ level metrics

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

Can we have ECS task metrics over the availability zone,
say I have 2 tasks in 1a, 2 in 1b can i have seperate metrics for each of the Availabilty Zone.

I went through these docs:-

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-metrics.html

but did not find a way.

Comment: You could probably do that after enabling Container Insights (which is not free) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights.html but the bigger question is why do you care about what AZ the task is in?

Comment: @MarkB thanks for sharing the doc, the requirement is to monitor tasks in each AZ seperately since due to AZ we can have latency in our service.